# rcu_read_lock and x86-64 memory ordering

Tags: linux, x86, memory-barriers, rcu

On a preemptible SMP kernel, `rcu_read_lock` compiles the following:

```
current->rcu_read_lock_nesting++;
barrier();
```

With `barrier` being a compiler directive that compiles to nothing.

So, according to Intel's X86-64 memory ordering white paper:

> Loads may be reordered with older stores to different locations

why is the implementation actually OK?

Consider the following situation:

```
rcu_read_lock();
read_non_atomic_stuff();
rcu_read_unlock();
```

What prevents `read_non_atomic_stuff` from "leaking" forward past `rcu_read_lock`, causing it to run concurrently with the reclamation code running in another thread?

Comment: huh? `barrier()` is a compiler memory barrier, so no accesses inside rcu region can pass the lock or unlock function. Moreover, as the manual clearly says, loads cannot be reordered with older stores to the *same* locations.

Comment: @HadiBrais
But wouldn't loads inside the read-side critical section be re-ordered in hardware with `rcu_read_lock`, which is a load and a store to a counter? If so, why is this OK?

Comment: @HadiBrais: `read_non_atomic_stuff()` is accessing *different* memory than `current->rcu_read_lock_nesting`.  Yes there would be possible StoreLoad reordering if an observer on another core read it without taking special precautions.  But those special precautions are part of the point of RCU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For observers on other CPUs, nothing prevents this.  You're right, StoreLoad reordering of the store part of `++` can make it globally visible after some of your loads.

**Thus we can conclude that `current->rcu_read_lock_nesting` is only ever observed by code running on this core,** or that has remotely triggered a memory barrier on this core by getting scheduled here, or with a dedicated mechanism for getting all cores to execute a barrier in a handler for an inter-processor interrupt (IPI).  e.g. similar to the `membarrier()` user-space system call.

---

If this core starts running another task, that task is guaranteed to see this task's operations in program order.  (Because it's on the same core, and a core always sees its own operations in order.)  Also, context switches might involve a full memory barrier so tasks can be resumed on *another* core without breaking single-threaded logic.  (That would make it safe for any core to look at `rcu_read_lock_nesting` when this task / thread is not running anywhere.)

**Notice that the kernel starts one RCU task per core of your machine**; e.g. `ps` output shows `[rcuc/0]`, `[rcuc/1]`, ..., `[rcu/7]` on my 4c8t quad core.  Presumably they're an important part of this design that lets readers be wait-free with no barriers.

I haven't looked into full details of RCU, but one of the "toy" examples in 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt is "classic RCU" that implements     `synchronize_rcu()`  as `for_each_possible_cpu(cpu) run_on(cpu);`, to get the reclaimer to execute on every core that might have done an RCU operation (i.e. every core).  Once that's done, we know that a full memory barrier must have happened in there somewhere as part of the switching.

So yes, RCU doesn't follow the classic method where you'd need a full memory barrier (including StoreLoad) to make the core wait until the first store was visible before doing any reads.  **RCU avoids the overhead of a full memory barrier in the read path.**  This is one of the major attractions for it, besides the avoidance of contention.